# i want to validate mobile number using java code not javascript

Tags: validation

I am using the validate function of the Struts.
 So I want to validation the mobile number of 10 digits that every digit of the mobile number must be an integer.

I have used `mobileno.contains()` method but I am not achieve the functionality properly.

```
<tr>
                <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap><bean:message key="sp.mbno"/></td>
                <td nowrap align="left" ><html:text property="mobileno" name="reg"/></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Why the people making it negative. I was in need for this :/

Comment: The reson for the downvotes are probably because you have shown no research effort. Questions like: I need this, give me the code, tends to get downvotes, but questions like: "I need this and this is what i've tried and there is an error in this line" will give you upvotes

Comment: @Jimmmy Gustafsson thanx for showing your concern. I will take care of this thing next thing. I will put the code that i have tried next tym....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*
     * Returns true if string contains atlesat one alphabet(lowercase or uppercase).
     */
    public static boolean containsAtLeastOneAlphabet(String str)
    {
        int x;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < str.length() ; j++)
        {
            x = (int)str.charAt(j);
            if((x >= 65 && x <= 90) || (x >= 97 && x <= 122))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: @ Ravi Jain Thanx my problem is solved too :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use apache StringUtils for this. It's a handy toolset for String operations:

e.g. have a look at the API for StringUtils.isNumeric:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.String%29